# I want to sort it so that I can see value counts of only H risk segmentation

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaaTQ.png)

I want to sort it so that I can see value counts of only "H" risk segmentation. L and M should not be there.

```
masterdata[['STATE_x_x','RISK_SEGMENTATION_x'== H]].value_counts()
```

it showed error then

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your index and mask your dataframe after the value count:

```
df = masterdata[['STATE_x_x','RISK_SEGMENTATION_x']].value_counts().reset_index()
df[df['RISK_SEGMENTATION_x'== 'H']]
```